# Looking for a series of short stories about soldiers who had prescient abilities

Tags: military-sf, story-identification

I believe these stories were first written in the 80's, and the main arc was about soldiers who had been found to have time warping, telepathic and prescient abilities. It was very 'X men' in nature but with a real narrative, taking place in what seemed to be the Vietnam war.

The first story centered around a research project funded by a Government agency that observed (and sometimes sent off to die) these soldiers in order to find the root cause and possibly replicate their abilities. It was inferred that the stress of combat had brought out latent abilities that allow some individuals to become 'super soldiers'.

One story in particular featured a nurse who had a relationship with both the soldiers under observation and the 'lead researcher' who was only looking for results. The nurse herself develops the ability to see into the future.

There were follow on stories about these soldiers and their descendants, taking place in present day and in the future. I believe there were at least half a dozen stories written in Asimov's SF or one of the other paper back short story monthlies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cold-war telepathic super-soldiers](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69072/cold-war-telepathic-super-soldiers)

Comment: @JoeL.
I don't think so. I read that one, in an effort to answer the question you mention above. And it does not match.

Answer (score 4):

[Bruce McAllister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_McAllister), *[Dream Baby](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3324379-dream-baby)*, 1987.

First as a short story, often found in anthologies, then as a novel, in 1989.

> Young Army nurse Mary Damico dreams the deaths of soldiers before they happen, but cannot save them. Only when she is recruited for a secret unit of other ESP "talents"—one run by a rogue CIA psychiatrist who may be a "talent" himself—can she become the psychic warrior she needs to be to stop the insanity and save those she loves.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add some details about the specific stories, perhaps describing some of the events that match the question?